# OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: python, gridsearchcv

when I run a python program with gridSearch or randomSearch at some point I get this error, what does it means and how to solve? There is a lot of disk space, 32GB ram and I don't know how this could happen.

```
File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_memmapping_reducer.py", line 339, in __call__
    for dumped_filename in dump(a, filename):
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 502, in dump
    NumpyPickler(f, protocol=protocol).dump(value)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/pickle.py", line 408, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 289, in save
    wrapper.write_array(obj, self)
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/numpy_pickle.py", line 104, in write_array
    pickler.file_handle.write(chunk.tostring('C'))
OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 502, in <module>
    neuralNetwork(dataset)
  File "main.py", line 245, in neuralNetwork
    best_model_temp=innerKeras(model, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test)
  File "main.py", line 229, in innerKeras
    best_model,cv_results =ut.getBestModelAndResults(X_train,y_train,model, dataset.keras_param, useRandomSearch=True)
  File "/home/tombari/bankrupty/src/utility.py", line 203, in getBestModelAndResults
    grid=getRandomSearchCvAndFit(X_train,y_train,model, hyperparameters)
  File "/home/tombari/bankrupty/src/utility.py", line 188, in getRandomSearchCvAndFit
    random.fit(X_train, y_train)
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 722, in fit
    self._run_search(evaluate_candidates)
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 1515, in _run_search
    random_state=self.random_state))
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_search.py", line 711, in evaluate_candidates
    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 930, in __call__
    self.retrieve()
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 833, in retrieve
    self._output.extend(job.get(timeout=self.timeout))
  File "/home/tombari/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/_parallel_backends.py", line 521, in wrap_future_result
    return future.result(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 398, in result
```

Comment: Are you executing it on jupyter?

Comment: How much disk space is "a lot"? Because this error usually means it's "not enough". It might be trying to write to a partition that's too small (e.g. `/tmp/` is usually quite size limited), even as other partitions have more than enough space.

Comment: I execute from command line `python3 main.py`
here is the space left

`$ df -h /tmp
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       118G   34G   78G  30% /`